# how to open specific window after clicking on notification in titanium

Tags: android, ios, titanium, localnotification

i want to open a certain page in the app when i click on notification in titanium 
i'm using titanium SDK 3.5.1
i have created an intent that lanch the app but it open the index page

```
var intent1 = Ti.Android.createIntent({
    flags : Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED | Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP,
    className : 'co.ntime.audioPlayer.AudioplayerActivity',
    action : Ti.Android.ACTION_MAIN
});
var pending1 = Ti.Android.createPendingIntent({
    activity : Ti.Android.currentActivity,
    intent : intent1,
    type : Ti.Android.PENDING_INTENT_FOR_ACTIVITY,
    flags : Titanium.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
});
Ti.Android.currentActivity.addEventListener('newintent', function(e) {
    Ti.API.info('caught intent!');
    var page1 = Alloy.createController('page1').getView();
    $.index.add(page1);
});
```

but it doesn't enter the new intent event

Answer (score 0):

You have to send extra field as string in your pushnotification which you can check onMessage() method then based on that extra field string you can set the Activity class using if else.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I'm not using native android i using cross platform Titanium

Comment: same goes for another platform also, I mean to say logic is same for other platform

Comment: From the server you have to send message field with extra field string which defined which page to be shown. Get both field in your code and apply if else logic

Comment: i'm using local notification sorry i didn't say that

Comment: @user3570141 Please specify in your question that you are using local notification.

Answer (score 0):

On my projects i added extra field on my push notification eg. pushID. This field is then read when opening the notification and depending on that field's value, the specific page is opened corresponding that value.

ex. pushID = 1, visit login page
ex2. pushID =2, visit contacts page and so on...

Answer (score 0):

i found an answer  here is code

```
var intent1 = Ti.Android.createIntent({
    flags : Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP,
    className : 'co.ntime.audioPlayer.AudioplayerActivity',
    action : 1
});
intent1.putExtra('button', 'my first activity');
var pending1 = Ti.Android.createPendingIntent({
    activity : Ti.Android.currentActivity,
    intent : intent1,
    type : Ti.Android.PENDING_INTENT_FOR_ACTIVITY,
    flags : Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
});
Ti.Android.currentActivity.addEventListener('newintent', function(e) {
    Ti.API.info('caught intent!');
     var page1 = Alloy.createController('page1').getView();
     $.index.open();
     $.index.add(page1);
     anAudioPlayer.pause();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var theNextWindow = Alloy.createController("PageName");
Alloy.Globals.pageStack.open(theNextWindow.getView());
```